# How to load more data in RecyclerView when Scrolling on Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from `json` and show its in `RecyclerView` every 10 posts and when user scrolling on `RecyclerView` show more 10 post and go to end!
I am amateur and i write below codes, **but I don't know** to to read more data when scrolling and go to next page! (I want show any 10 posts in any pages).
**Json link :** [JSON LINK](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1)

**AsyncTask codes:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            JSONObject images=postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair=images.optJSONObject("medium");

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String content = postObject.getString("content");
                            String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + thumbnail);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, thumbnail));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this code for show any pages posts : **`ServerAddress + "page=1"`**

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class MainAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<MainDataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public MainAdapter2(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<MainDataModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle());
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void add(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter2 mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModelsArray;
    private Context context;
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        LoadData();
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdaper = new MainAdapter2(this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);

        mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {

            }
        });


    }


    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        final MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
    }
```

for load more data i use **Interface** class : `OnLoadMoreListener`

**Attention :** I know the name of this method is endless! but i am amateur and i don't know to write code in `mAdapter.setOnMoreListener` to load more data! Please don't give me negative points, help me and i really need you helps! thanks all <3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58362743/10910275

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add onLoadMoreListener to your adapter,

```
  adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(onLoadMoreListener);
```

Then Implement below code in onLoadMore():

```
OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener = new OnLoadMoreListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore() {
        //Here adding null object to last position,check the condition in getItemViewType() method,if object is null then display progress
        dataModels.add(null);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());

                // Call you API, then update the result into dataModels, then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). 
                //Update the new data into list object
                loadData();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loading = false;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

Your method:

```
      private void LoadData() {
             MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
            // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
             dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you man,In fact, I do not know this code : `// Call you API, then update the result into dataModels, then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().` What should I write code here?

Comment: Call new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");, Here page=1 means the limit of the object which we are getting from API...right?? If it's right then pass page=2, then you will get other 10 object from API.

Comment: Can you write this code and edit you above post? please write this code here! please please please , i really need this help and tutorial. please <3

Comment: Are you getting first 10 object from server?? because in adapter your sending empty list object. Where are you updating that list. bus.post(listObject); what it will do?

Comment: I read first 10 posts from server, and send this with `bus.post(infoModels);` and show in the `RecyclerView`. empty list?! i haven't empty list because show all first 10 post in Recyclerview!

Comment: bus.post(infoModels) will it update your mDataset list object in your adapter class...?

Comment: I am unable to open that link, please post your error in comments or in your query.

Comment: I don't use bus in Adapter! i just use `bus.post(infoModels)` in `onPostExecute` in asynctask and mainActivity for give data!

Comment: please refresh topic and show error image in new answer

Comment: first load 10 object on recycler view. Then start with loadMore data.

Comment: first 10 objects show in Recyclerview, but i can't show other 10 post!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110347/discussion-between-f-feed-and-saritha-g).

Comment: If it is showing in recycler view then dont do anything. look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for help. it's ok! but i have strange bug! :D when scroll recyclerview show again first 10 post! not load more post!

Comment: I know. bus.post() updating only for first time. you should update dataModels list object for every 10 post's.