# Loads more for second RecyclerView - android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have below layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/signsRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And below layout is items of above RecyclerView, in this layout I have another RecyclerView. How can I have loads more for second `RecyclerView` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardVisibleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                android:id="@+id/itxtArrow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/fa_chevron_down"
                android:textColor="@color/orangePeel" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCategoryName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardVisibleLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcyNested"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you:

[How to load more data in RecyclerView when Scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882213/how-to-load-more-data-in-recyclerview-when-scrolling-on-android)

So step by step:

1. Add `OnScrollListener` to your `RecyclerView` to detect when you want to load more (for example load more if you are at last item)
2. Create an interface for the more loading:

   `public interface OnLoadMoreCallback { void onLoadMore(); }`
3. Implement the interface. Inside the `onLoadMore()` you can call for example a rest api. For this you can use `AsyncTask`.
4. After you loaded new data you have to update the datamodels and notify your adapter that the data has been added.

Comment: Can you write an example? Thanks

Comment: The link is the example ;)