# recyclerview scroll and stay in old position dont go top

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

my problem is when I scroll my data in recycle view So new data loading but problem is when new data is loading my recycle view start from first product,

I need to stay old position and scroll only new data not all data old and new

currently I am adding full code of my file adeptoer file and home file,

```
public class adepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adepter.viewholder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Product> productList;
        public adepter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
            this.mCtx = mCtx;
            this.productList = productList;
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public adepter.viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
        final viewholder vh = new viewholder(v);
        vh.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Product product = productList.get(vh.getAdapterPosition());
                //do the page opening here
                Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, product_info.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",product.getId());

                mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return vh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adepter.viewholder holder, int position) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);
        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(product.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());
        holder.textViewtype.setText(String.valueOf(product.getType()));
        holder.textViewPrice.setText("Rs: "+String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }





    public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewtype, textViewPrice;
        ImageView imageView;
        public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
            textViewtype = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

  //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;
    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar Pbar;
    GridLayoutManager manager;
    int token = 1;
  Boolean isScrolling = false;
    int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Pbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();





        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
                {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems))
                {
                    isScrolling = false;
                    token++;
                    getData();
                }
            }
        });
        getData();


    }





    private void   getData(){
         String url = "https://shop.com/index.php";

         url = url+ "&pg="+ String.valueOf(token);

        Pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"volly ok ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                //adding the product to product list
                                productList.add(new Product(
                                        product.getInt("id"),
                                        product.getString("title"),
                                        product.getString("shortdesc"),
                                        product.getString("type"),
                                        product.getString("price"),
                                        product.getString("image")
                                ));
                            }
                            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),productList+ "volly ok ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                          adepter a = new adepter(home.this, productList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(a);

                            Pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to load data when RecyclerView is scrolling, right or wrong

Comment: @JimaleAbdi sir recycle view is scrolling but problem is after scrolling data load properly but recyclerview start from first item

Comment: Why you not fetch data in onCreate instead of onScrolling? also if your purpose is to know if there is new data in your server we can solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

  //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;
    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    adepter a;
    ProgressBar Pbar;
    GridLayoutManager manager;
    int token = 1;
  Boolean isScrolling = false;
    int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Pbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();


 a = new adepter(home.this, productList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(a);


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
                {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems))
                {
                    isScrolling = false;
                    token++;
                    getData();
                }
            }
        });
        getData();


    }





    private void   getData(){
         String url = "https://shop.com/index.php";

         url = url+ "&pg="+ String.valueOf(token);

        Pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"volly ok ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                //adding the product to product list
                                productList.add(new Product(
                                        product.getInt("id"),
                                        product.getString("title"),
                                        product.getString("shortdesc"),
                                        product.getString("type"),
                                        product.getString("price"),
                                        product.getString("image")
                                ));
                            }
                            a.notifyDataSetChanged();



                            Pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```